# Seleccionar dos datos diferentes en Combobox Dinamicos c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, mvc, formularios, usercontrol

Hola quisiera ver si alguien me puede ayudar.
Tengo un un combobox en un **UserControl**, al momento de leer ese **UserControl** se clona n cantidad de veces, al combobox le asigne un name según el numero que va en el foreach pero al momento de seleccionar un combobox todos los clones de mi control seleccionan el mismo campo.
Yo necesito que se puedan seleccionar distintos campos ejemplo

1. Seleccione en el Combobox1 Marta.
2. Seleccione en el Combobox2 Julia.

Actualmente esta así

1. Seleccione Marta en el Combobox1
2. Los otros Combobox tienen Marta por defecto.

**CODIGO DEL USERCONTROL**

```
        try
        {
            if ((strDescError.Trim().Length == 0) && (dsCombo != null) && (dsCombo.Tables.Count > 0) && (dsCombo.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0))
            {
                cbCategory.DisplayMember = dsCombo.Tables[0].TableName;
                cbCategory.DataSource = dsCombo.Tables[0];
                cbCategory.ValueMember = "Customer_Id";
                cbCategory.DisplayMember = "Category_Name";
                cbCategory.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                //cbCategory.DataSource = null;
                if (cbCategory.DataSource == null)
                    cbCategory.Items.Clear();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            strDescError = "Error al cargar los datos del combobox";
            throw;
        }

        cbCategory.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        cbCategory.Name = String.Format("cbCategory0{0}", number);
```

**CODIGO DE FORMULARIO**

DataSet dsResult;
dsResult = (DataSet)e.Result;

```
        if (dsResult.Tables.Count < 1)
        {
            string msg = "No se puede realizar la transacción, verifique que la guía cuente con piezas declaradas";
            //MessageBox.Show(msg, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }

        // add default selection
        DataRow dtRowCountry = dsResult.Tables[0].NewRow();
        dtRowCountry.SetField("Customer_Id", "-1");
        dtRowCountry.SetField("Category_Name", "[SELECCIONE]");
        dsResult.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(dtRowCountry, 0);

        // continue
        containers = Convert.ToInt32(dsResult.Tables[1].Rows[0]["Total_Pieces"].ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i < containers; i++)
        {
            var pieceControl = new MyUserControl(i, dsResult);
            pieceControl.Name = string.Format("myUserControl0{0}", i + 1);
            var controls = pieceControl.Controls.Find("cbCategory", true);
            var cb = (ComboBox)controls[0];
            cb.Name = String.Format("cbCategory0{0}", i + 1);
            flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(pieceControl);
            flowLayoutPanel.Focus();
        }
```

Muchas gracias de Antemano si me ayudan.